# codeigniter upload image store userfile in database rather than image name

Tags: codeigniter, image-upload

[Database output: userfile rather than image name?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H72Zu.png)
rather than 
CONTROLLER:
my upload directory is fine but when i use another method and call it when needed it doesnt give my desired output.. im very sorry for novicity

`

```
 public function uploadImage()
    {       
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/files';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
        $config['max_size'] = '2048';
        $config['max_width'] = '2000';
        $config['max_height'] = '2000';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        if ( !$this->upload->do_upload()){
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            echo "<script>window.alert('failed to load UserFile');</script>";
        }else{
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            $post_image = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
            echo "<script>window.alert('your image has been successfully uploaded');</script>";
        }
    }
```

`

```
public function signupPost()
{

    if ($this->form_validation->run('signup') == FALSE) {
        //fails wont continue to next page
        $this->signup_view();
    } else {
        //upload image
        $this->uploadImage();
        //insert data into the database
        $data = array(
            'userId' => $this->input->post('userId'),
            'userfile'  => $this->input->post('userfile'),
            );
        //user data has successfully signed up
        $this->User->signup_client($data);
        redirect('http://localhost/GFC/index.php/main','refresh');
    }
}
```

VIEW:

```
<?php 
        $attributes = array("name" => "signupform");
        $hidden = array('userId' => 'userId', 'userfile' => 'userfile');
        echo form_open_multipart("Client_Dashboard/signupPost", $attributes, $hidden);
    ?>
<div class="w3-row">
                    <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" style="margin-left:30%; margin-top:8%;"/>
                    <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('userfile'); ?></span>
                </div>

    <div class="container" style="padding:0%;">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Register" class=" w3-btn w3-teal w3-large w3-hover-white w3-padding-large" />

    </div>
        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not specifying the input and not returning the name of image to your function

```
function uploadImage() {       
  $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/files';
  $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
  $config['max_size'] = '2048';
  $config['max_width'] = '2000';
  $config['max_height'] = '2000';
  $this->load->library('upload', $config);

  if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){
    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    // var_dump($error); die; // check error
  } else {
    $fileName = $this->upload->data();
    return $fileName;
  }
}

function signupPost() {

  if ($this->form_validation->run('signup') == FALSE) {
    // fails wont continue to next page
    $this->signup_view();
  } else {
    // upload image
    $data['UserFile'] = $this->uploadImage();
    // insert data into the database
    $data = array(
       'userId' => $this->input->post('userId'),
       'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
       'emailAddress' => $this->input->post('emailAddress'),
       'userfile'  => $this->input->post('userfile'),
       'branchId'  => $this->input->post('branchId')
    );

   // user data has successfully signed up
   $this->User->signup_client($data);
   redirect('http://localhost/GFC/index.php/main', 'refresh');
 }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the fast answer @muhammadusman. this means a lot. is there other possible reason for this? like the way i setup my database structure?... it didnt worked out.

Comment: Show me your db structure?

Comment: no error but the output in database is "userfile" rather than the name of the image..

Comment: Column: UserFile, varchar 255,MIME type:none

Comment: echo $post_image; die; check what is storing in varibale

Comment: array(1) { ["error"]=> string(86) "
The image you are attempting to upload doesn't fit into the allowed dimensions.

" }

Comment: Mention the error. Try an image with allowed dimensions.

Comment: i can already see the data that should be saved on database and its incrementing a value of one so i think its good right?.. my next problem is that how can i call $post_image variable into signupPost function.. inside the $data array?

Comment: Ah you are not returning an name to function. let me modify your code

Comment: what is branch id you are using in image function

Comment: the only $data that i used in saving image is only the userfile. the other inputs are used in other text fields..

Comment: i checked your code similarly and still could'nt find the reason why it store NULL on database

Comment: thanks for the help.. i realized the only reason it did not  store because my model cannot insert two array's which it will choose from. your code above is perfect for what i need.                                                        
                     `$data = array(
    'userId' => $this->input->post('userId'),
    'UserFile' => $this->uploadImage()
        );`